# PostgreSQL Slony replication - scheduled sync

Tags: postgresql, replication, slony

I am migrating Oracle database into Postgres and I need to implement replication of the master database to multiple slave dbs. The replication should be executed once a day at specified time (to take the load off the dbs) and only replicate the data that was changed.

I am trying to achieve that using Slony - it seems to do what I need except it syncs the data in short intervals. I haven't been able to find any information on how to configure Slony for scheduled sync, is it even possible?
Or do I have to launch slon daemons at desired time and then kill them using some script/scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can specify `lag_interval` to set sync within specified interval,  here is the [documentation](http://slony.info/documentation/slon-config-interval.html) . You can specify this option for Slony daemon with `-l` [option](http://slony.info/documentation/2.1/slon.html).